# WebView2 NewWindowRequested Overwriting Existing Window

Tags: webview2

I have a WPF app that uses webview2. When users navigate to a certain URL, there are links to pdfs that will open in a new window. The problem I am trying to address is that the new windows don't respect the sizing of the browser (a known issue with wv2).

Based on what I am reading, I can address this by setting the NewWindow property on the CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs to my existing webview2's CoreWebView2, but when I do that, it:

1. Doesn't open the new window
2. Overwrites the existing window with a blank page

**Version**
**Version**: WebView2 1.0.902.49
**.NET Framework** 4.7.2
**OS** Wind10

[image]

**Additional notes:**

Even when I comment out all the above code and throw a debugger in that method to inspect the event args, it still overwrites the existing window (though all code is commented out). However, it only seems to do this when I hit the debugger and if I remove it, the window remains and the popup opens.

When I inspect the uri given, it is "about:blank#blocked", which is likely why the page is blank. So if I can't get the actual uri / url for this pdf, I can't open it in the new window even if I could get this to work.

Comment: e.Handled = true is required in order to commandeer the new window's behavior, which I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs.NewWindow` property to tell WebView2 where to show the new window. If you set NewWindow to the CoreWebView2 that fired the event, then the new window will take over the existing CoreWebView2.

You'll need to create your own new window (or whatever UI is appropriate) containing a new WebView2 and set the `CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs.NewWindow` property to that new CoreWebView2 if you want to have control over a new window with a new WebView2.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: Do you happen to have some example code of this (creating a new window), or some documentation that does? I'm trying to do this (with WPF) but when I initialize the Webview2 and call `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`, the `Task` never completes for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I created a generic container for WebView2, and allow the application users - developers and analysts deploying it in their systems - to define how they would like to handle new windows, i.e., open in same web view, open in new web view, open in default browser, or block.

```
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (viewModel.Configuration.NewWindow)
    {
        case SharedComponents.BrowserWindow.NewWindowOption.BLOCK:
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        case SharedComponents.BrowserWindow.NewWindowOption.OPEN:
            e.Handled = false;
            break;
        case SharedComponents.BrowserWindow.NewWindowOption.OPENNEW:
            string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string workingFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            viewModel.StartNewWebViewer(exePath, workingFolder, e.Uri);
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        case SharedComponents.BrowserWindow.NewWindowOption.OPENSAME:
            e.Handled = true;
            this.webView.Source = new Uri(e.Uri);
            break;
        default:
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

The code for launching the new window looks like this, where I use the defining parameters of the app, along with the new URL, to launch a new window of the base app, and that hosts its own WebVeiw2:

```
Public Sub StartNewWebViewer(exePath As String, workingFolder As String, newPath As String) Implements IViewModel.StartNewWebViewer

    Dim processString = If(Configuration.TitleVisibility = Visibility.Visible, "", "-hideTitle ")
    processString &= If(Configuration.DisplayMskIcon = Visibility.Visible, "-showIcon ", "")
    processString &= If(Configuration.ResizeWindow = True, "", "-noResize ")
    processString = String.Format("{0} -nw {1} -u ""{2}"" -t ""{3}"" -g {4} -l {5}", processString, Configuration.NewWindow.ToString(), newPath, Configuration.Title, ParentGuid, loggingName)

    Dim newProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    With newProcessStartInfo
        .FileName = exePath
        .Arguments = processString
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = False
        .RedirectStandardInput = False
        .ErrorDialog = True
        .Verb = "runas"
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .WorkingDirectory = workingFolder
    End With

    Using newProcess As New Process()
        With newProcess
            .StartInfo = newProcessStartInfo
            .Start()
        End With
    End Using

End Sub
```